# Getting Gmail app for Android to render my HTML email?

Tags: android, html, email, gmail

I'm currently at a stand still and could really use some help. I'm coding an HTML email which is a first for me. I have a basic understanding of CSS and HTML, but I can't figure out for the life of me how to fix this Gmail problem, and I even know what the cause is. It seems as though the problem is coming from the only editable text region, which is the address line (Hi [name],) and which is also the only row with multiple columns. It looks like the text isn't shrinking to fit the screen, causing the neighboring cells to go crazy and expand the picture. It works great in every other ESP I tested it on, even Outlook. I attached a picture and my code. Please, if you have any advice or resources please help a noob in need.

[messed up version on Android Gmail app](http://i.imgur.com/UivU3FF.png)
[code](http://jsfiddle.net/frickenbill/tQRM5/)

```
<html>

<head>
    <title>Tradeshow_email_PARTY</title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <!-- Save for Web Slices (Tradeshow_email_PARTY.jpg) -->
    <table id="Table_01" width="600" height="1046" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/m2GZSwm.png" style="display:block" width="600" height="408" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RyJDbPa.png" style="display:block" width="47" height="40" alt="">
            </td>
            <td width="123" height="40" style="line-height: 0pt; font-weight: bolder;"><font face="arial" size="2px" color="#636564">Hi [name],</font>

            </td>
            <td>
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KUO971D.png" style="display:block" width="430" height="40" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/nWU4N6L.png" style="display:block" width="600" height="598" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should nest your columns instead of colspanning it. Setting widths on the all table cells that are not 100% of the row is important also. Example:

```
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <!-- Save for Web Slices (Tradeshow_email_PARTY.jpg) -->
    <table id="Table_01" width="600" height="1046" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/m2GZSwm.png" style="display:block" width="600" height="408" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
              <table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                <tr>
                  <td width="47">
                      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RyJDbPa.png" style="display:block" width="47" height="40" alt="">
                  </td>
                  <td width="123" height="40" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight: bold; color:#636564;">
                    Hi [name],
                  </td>
                  <td width="40">
                      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KUO971D.png" style="display:block" width="430" height="40" alt="">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/nWU4N6L.png" style="display:block" width="600" height="598" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
```

You'll notice a few other small things I fixed up for you also. Ultimately though, you are using a lot of images in places where you shouldn't. Your grey sides should be in html and so should all text from the red area down.

Comment: thank you for the feedback. As I'm sure you can tell, I'm a rookie at this and kind of filled the void with in the company. I understand that my approach could have been improved, but I was given a jpeg and a timeframe lol. Photoshop is the easiest way I know how to slice an image into an html table, so that's what I did. Moving forward, I will definitely take a better approach though. I appreciate your help, its much cleaner code, but still looks the same on the Gmail app. Still works well in other ESPs though. Seriously, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

This is my try based on above code:

```
<body bgcolor="#FFFFFF" leftmargin="0" topmargin="0" marginwidth="0" marginheight="0">
    <!-- Save for Web Slices (Tradeshow_email_PARTY.jpg) -->
    <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/m2GZSwm.png" style="display:block" width="600" height="408" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td width="600" style="width:600px;min-width:600px;max-width:600px;">
              <table width="600" border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="border-collapse:separate;">
                <tr>
                  <td width="47" style="width:47px;;min-width:47px;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
                      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RyJDbPa.png" style="display:block;min-width:47px;width:47px;" width="47" height="40" alt="">
                  </td>
                  <td width="123" style="font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size:12px; font-weight: bold; color:#636564;width:123px;min-width:123px;">
                    Hi [name],
                    </td>
                  <td width="430" style="width:430px;min-width:430px;">
                      <img src="http://i.imgur.com/KUO971D.png" style="display:block;width:430px;min-width:430px;" width="430" height="40" alt="">
                  </td>
                </tr>
              </table>

            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <img src="http://i.imgur.com/nWU4N6L.png" style="display:block" width="600" height="598" alt="">
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <!-- End Save for Web Slices -->
</body>
```